# WCF Error (Timeout)

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a client and WCF service running..

When a client tried to talk to WCF (i.e. getting a result from WCF), it throws the exception below..

**The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9062420'.**

So, I did search on Google and found threads on Stackoverflow. I tried to increase the timeout on the client as below

```
<netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceEndpoint"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" >
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

And then I got the following error:

**The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:09:59.8593729'.**

When I debug the WCF Service, it is actually not taking long at all. It immediately returns a result. (it only validates the log in information by querying the database and return it immediately). So, my guess is not related to timeout at all.. but I don't know how to resolve it..

Please help...

Comment: Enable the trace in wcf and watch for the traces file

Comment: Links to help you get started:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: After searching more, I found the following post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441844/the-socket-connection-was-aborted-communicationexception  I am referencing the Entity (generated by EF) directly in my client. Now, I need to add DataCotract attribute to the all entity generated by EF. But since those are auto-generated, what is the best way to do this? Manually create another layer (says Domain) and map it to the Entity generated by EF?

Comment: had you solved the issue, share with others

Comment: No..I haven't solved it yet..  I found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000142/converting-entity-framework-model-to-data-contract and it said I don't need to put DataContract attribute.. I am now confused...

Comment: You will be required to use a DTO or refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405909/wcf-entity-framework-how-to-get-a-nice-datacontract

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, which was solved by removing the <security> element altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue

In my case, the exception "The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message" received on client-side hide the real exception thrown on Server-Side (server thrown a FaultException because data doesn't respect validation rule).

For me, the error was really a Serialization issue : one the field in the input payload was incorrect (enum value is 0 for an enum witch have value between 1 and 7)